# Cannot import Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, pip, conda, tensorflow2.0

I can't import tensorflow, even after checking all dependencies. I'm getting an error message 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'' when importing 'import tensorflow as tf' in vs code

I installed tensorflow through conda with 'conda install tensorflow'. It seems to have worked, since when I use 'pip show tensorflow', it shows up as 'version 2.10.0'. Moreover, my Python version is '3.9.15', so it should be compatible. I've been looking all over and no other installatoins have been working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed? Where are you running your code? VS Code, PyCharm, Eclipse? If you are using virtual env then activate it. If you are using any IDE, then use its console/terminal to install required packages or alternatively use your global python interpreter for python project.

Comment: @AzharKhan I'm using VS Code and my conda is already activated. The interpreter I'm using is that same conda environment.

Comment: We should verify the source of the issue. One thing that might be useful is if you go in your terminal and do this,

1) activate the conda environment
2) run `python` to enter python shell
3) import tensorflow

let's forget about your IDE for now and use this to check the environment itself

Comment: @MikeL I just tried that in terminal and got a load of errors, followed by 'Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime' error.

Comment: Hi @wust, please do not install TensorFlow with conda. It may not have the latest stable version. pip is recommended since TensorFlow is only officially released to PyPI. Kindly follow the instructions to install Tensorflow from the official [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try again by using **Python version 3.10** as Python 3.9 shows some version errors in **VS code**.

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75262585/14290681) to install TensorFlow in **VScode**.