# Error when installing TensorFlow through pip

Tags: tensorflow, installation, pip, conda

I'm following the instructions from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#python-version-support to install tensorflow. I've used tensorflow before but for some reason, it has just stopped working. I'm using VS Code.

First, I check that pip and python are compatible:

```
python3 --version
python3 -m pip --version
```

I have Python 3.10.8, with pip 22.3.1 so it should be compatible. Then, I create a conda environment and activate it:

```
conda create --name tf python=3.9
conda activate tf
```

However, now when I try

```
pip install tensorflow
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

How can I fix this? I also tried things in the past like installing tensorflow through Conda, but I get errors when importing tensorflow there.

Comment: Have you tried using the `conda install` method instead? Given you're using a conda environment, you may see more consistent installation results with a conda install instead of pip

Comment: @MikeL Yeah I have. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74990047/cannot-import-tensorflow this is the link to the question I asked recently, since I got errors using conda install as well.

Comment: Responded there. I strongly suspect the conda-side issue is IDE config, not a conda problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try again by opening anaconda cmd propmt and run below code:

```
conda create --name tf_new python=3.10
conda activate tf_new
```

then install tensorflow using:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Now open the VS code by selecting the same created VirEnv **tf_new** from Anaconda navigator.

In **VScode**, Open a new jupyter notebook file and run the below code by selecting the **tf_new** (Conda VirEnv) in kernel(from top right) .

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

Output:

```
'2.11.0'
```